# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, python-3.x

"хотел создать дискорд бота" ,после чего добавил функцию мьют и при того когда человек не указал кого хочет мьютет, то бот должен писать вы не указали. Но почему-то он не хочет принимать error, а вот на других функциях на пример бан или кик все работает нормально, что меня сильно озадачило

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Mod")

async def person_mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit =1)

    mute_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "Daun" )

    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} < -- он даун")

@person_mute.error
async def mute_person_error( ctx, error):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send( f" {ctx.author.name}, Вы не написали кого кикать!")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingAnyRole):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name}, У вас нет прав для этой команде, она позволена только для Mod")
```

вот пример где код работает:

```
@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True, )
@commands.has_any_role("Mod")

async def clear( ctx, amount : int ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )

# error
@clear.error
async def clear_error( ctx, error):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send( f" {ctx.author.name}, вы не ввели число!")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingAnyRole):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name}, У вас нет прав для этой команде, она позволена только для Mod")
```

Буду рад вашей помощи!

Comment: А покажите функции, где этот атрибут `error` нормально работает, чтобы было с чем сравнить. Добавьте их код в вопрос.

Comment: изменил, как вы и хотели

Answer (score 0):

Не понял как и не могу это объяснить, но сам додумалься и написал сверху методу mute.

Просто:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
```

.